# Живой поиск с несколькими вписанными словами JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть такой код живого поиска. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при вписывании нескольких слов, например как тут я впишу "машина двор", мне показывались те варианты, в которых есть хоть одно слово из вписанных? То есть чтоб первая и вторая строка оставались, а третья убиралась, ну и наоборот. Вписываю "дом двор" и убирался только вторая строка, а 1 и 3 оставалась. Помогите пожалуйста

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".tabs .tab-2 #container #output").keyup(function(){
    _this = this;
    $.each($(".tabs .tab-2 #recontain a .reslov"), function() {
      if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
        $(this).hide();
      else
        $(this).show();                
    });
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-2">
    <div>
      <div id="container">  
          <input id='output'>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2">
    <div>
      <div id="recontain" class="elastic">
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">
            <h6 id="reh6">машина, дом, улица, двор</h6>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">            
            <h6 id="reh6">машина, работа, офис, стол </h6>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">
            <h6 id="reh6">телефон, дом, ноутбук, </h6>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Поле ввода.
const INPUT = document.querySelector('#output')

// Корневой `HTMLElement` элемент списка доступных фраз.
const ROOT = document.querySelector('#recontain')

// Массив из `NodeList` списка элементов.
const NODES = Array.from(ROOT.children)

// Разбиваем коллекцию элементов с доступными
// фразами на массивы с сохранением индексов.
// В данном случае:
//     текст - заголовок `h6`,
//     разделитель - запятая.
const SPLITED = NODES.map(function(node) {
  return node.querySelector('h6')
    .innerText
    .split(/\s*,\s*/)
})

console.log(SPLITED)

function filterList(event) {
  // Строка из поля ввода.
  let searchString = event.target.value

  // Создаём массив слов из введённых
  // по пробелу, отфильтровав пустые.
  let searchArray = searchString.split(/(\s+)/)
    .filter(item => item.trim())

  // Проходимся по массиву с `node` элементами.
  NODES.forEach(function(node, nodeIndex) {
    // Проверяем, если хотя бы одно из `item` введённых слов
    // содержится в подготовленном массиве.
    let contains = searchArray.some(function(item) {
      return SPLITED[nodeIndex].includes(item.toLowerCase())
    })

    // В зависимости от критерия, щелкаем класс.
    contains ? node.classList.remove('hidden') : node.classList.add('hidden')
  })
}

// debounce возвращает вариант f,
// срабатывающий не чаще чем раз в ms миллисекунд
// https://learn.javascript.ru/task/debounce
function debounce(f, ms = 500) {
  let timer = null
  return function (...args) {
    const onComplete = () => {
      f.apply(this, args)
      timer = null
    }
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(onComplete, ms)
  }
}

// Вешаем функцию-обработчика на слушателя события.
// Событие input срабатывает тут же
// при изменении значения текстового элемента
INPUT.addEventListener('input', debounce(filterList))
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab-2">
    <div>
      <div id="container">
        <input id='output'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-2">
    <div>
      <div id="recontain" class="elastic">
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">
            <h6 id="reh6">машина, дом, улица, двор</h6>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">
            <h6 id="reh6">машина, работа, офис, стол </h6>
          </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#'>
          <div class="reslov">
            <h6 id="reh6">телефон, дом, ноутбук, </h6>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое))

Comment: еще вопрос, можно сделать так, чтобы оно обновлялось тут сразу при нажатии на чекбокс. Без нажатия на пробел все время?https://codepen.io/dduckker/pen/VOwmJG

Comment: Скорректировал. Чекбоксы не вставлял, вы уж сами попробуйте.

Comment: ну я  вот изменил, а оно все равно так https://codepen.io/dduckker/pen/eaYgey . Или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: Я не пойму, что вы там хотите сделать. Это уже видимо отдельная тема )

Comment: при нажатии на чек у меня добавляется в поле слово, и я хочу, чтобы оно сразу находило нужные строки(нажал на чек и нашло нужные строки, остальные убрало)